# Escrita na linha de comando via Lua, leitura da linha de comando via C#

Tags: c#, cmd, lua, linha-de-comando

Estava precisando de uma ajuda em um código em **lua**, para gerar parâmetros para a linha de comando, e depois recolhe-los por outra aplicação, só que em **C#**, para ser mais específico, quero executar um teclado virtual que fiz em **C#**, e nessa execução quero enviar os parâmetros das coordenadas de onde ele irá aparecer por lua, ou seja, se eu conseguir gerar os números de X e Y para a linha de comando por **lua** e recolhe-los por **C#**, consigo tratar a posição da tela.

O código atual que tinha encontrado por **lua** é:

```
local X = 20
local Y = 50

os.execute([[C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\netcoreapp3.1\\WindowsFormsApp2.exe X Y]])
```

Ele simplesmente executa meu teclado e talvez gera os argumentos de X e Y, mas não sei como estão sendo tratados.

E sobre o Código em **C#**, eu tenho como base:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2

{
    static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Test if input arguments were supplied.
            if (args.Length >= 0)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }



            Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Keyboard());
        }
    }
}
```

Mas não tenho certeza do que estou pegando, se é que estou, da linha de comando.
Alguém manja sobre isso ae pra me dar um Help?

Obs:

Sistema Operacional: Windows 10

```
     Programa C#: VisualStudio
```

Comment: quando você executa uma aplicação passando parâmetros elas vão vir no string[] args do main

Comment: Mas eu tenho que especificar a linha ou algo assim? Talvez um:







`int X = Console.ReadLine();
int Y = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: No caso em vez de **int** seria **string**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código lua não está passando as variáveis `X` e `Y` para a sua aplicação C#, perceba que você está enviando uma string, e nela, os caracteres em si, e não o valor contido nas variáveis. Para enviar o valor das variáveis é necessário concatena-las à string, você pode fazer isto utilizando [string.format](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.format):

```lua
local X = 20
local Y = 50

os.execute(string.format([[WindowsFormsApp2.exe %c %c]], X, Y))
```

E então na sua aplicação C# você consegue pega-las como argumento do método main:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args[0]); // Imprime o primeiro argumento (X)
    Console.WriteLine(args[1]); // Imprime o segundo argumento (Y)
}
```